# How can these people cross the bridge?

Tags: word-problem, algorithm

- There are 4 people that must cross an old dilapidated bridge at night, All four walk at different speeds:

  - There is a young teenager that can cross the bridge in 1 minute.
  - There is teenager's older brother can cross the bridge in 2 minutes.
  - Their father can cross the bridge in 5 minutes.
  - Their grandfather can cross the bridge in 10 minutes.
- Only two people can cross at a time otherwise the bridge will break.
- Also they have an oil lamp that will only last 17 minutes
- Any party that crosses the bridge (only one or two people) must have the oil lamp with them.
- If two people cross together, they have to walk at the speed of the slower person.

How can the entire group cross the bridge in 17 minutes?

The best answer I got was:

1. The teenager and the grandfather walk across the bridge with the oil lamp: 10 minutes
2. The teenager walks back with the oil lamp: 1 minute
3. The teenager and the father walk across the bridge with the oil lamp: 5 minutes
4. The teenager walks back with the oil lamp: 1 minute
5. The teenager and his older brother walk across the bridge with the oil lamp: 2 minutes

But that adds up to 19 minutes.

Comment: Note that this is a pretty well-known puzzle, with its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_and_torch_problem)

Answer (score 3):

They can cross in a total of:

> 17 minutes

Like this:

(To simplify, let's name the people A, B, C, and D, in order from fastest to slowest.)

- > A and B cross - 2 minutes, leaving CD|AB
- > A comes back - 1 minute, leaving ACD|B
- > C and D cross - 10 minutes, leaving A|BCD
- > B comes back - 2 minutes, leaving AB|CD
- > A and B cross - 2 minutes, leaving |ABCD

Comment: Yes this makes sense!